# Associative array remove all values of 0

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have an Associative array in PHP and want to remove all values which have the associated value of 0

`Array ( [item1] => 0 [item2] => 10 [item5] => 0 [item10] => 10 [item12] => 5 )`

Thank you

Comment: Look into [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of ways to achieve this, out of which two I have mentioned below:

- Use **[array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)**.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$arr = [
        'item1' => 0,
        'item2' => 10,
        'item5' => 0,
        'item10' => 10,
        'item12' => 5,
        'item120' => false,
    ];


$filtered = array_filter($arr,function($value){
    return $value !== 0;
});


print_r($filtered);
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/fMsHt

- Another way I would suggest is to use **[array_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)**

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$arr = [
        'item1' => 0,
        'item2' => 10,
        'item5' => 0,
        'item10' => 10,
        'item12' => 5,
        'item120' => false,
    ];


print_r(array_diff($arr,[0]));
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/3YHiX

Comment: @Wallchris Welcome to SO and glad to help :) Also, array_diff would work too.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this simply using array_filter

```
$data = Array ( 'item1' => 0 ,'item2' => 10, 'item5' => 0, 'item10' => 10, 'item12' => 5 );
 echo '<pre>';print_r(array_filter($data));
```